# How can I rewrite an internal/LAN URL using Apache rewrites?

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, url

Is it possible and how could I rewrite `http://192.168.1.1:4950/hello`   to, e.g., `http://home.hello`

I know how to use `.htaccess` to rewrite just part of URL's but can't figure out how to rewrite whole address including the IP part and port.

This rewriting is for internal/LAN use only.

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use a RewriteCond with the ServerName variable and then the RewriteRule would be a redirect.